# Regex for repeated numbers with predifined start

Tags: regex

I've got something for the regex experts here. I'm trying to check if there are any repeated sequences in a decimal number. At the moment I've got this working:

```
(\d{2,}?)\1
```

The problem is that this does not work very well with numbers like 0.00035 or 11125.5

Here it matches the 0.000 or the 111 as repeated sequences, and I don't want that to happen.

Is there a way to modify this regex to make it so it will only check after the decimal point, and exclude X number of zeroes from the first decimal places?

Comment: Which lang are you running? What's your expected output?

Comment: Language is Java. I want to find the first of a repeated sequence, so if I put in 0.025699999 the output should be 999(i think, could be less or more 9's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
[0-9]+\.0*+[0-9]*?([0-9]{2,})\1[0-9]*
```

The pattern uses a possessive quantifier `0*+` to prevent to match repeated zeros after the decimal separator. (the possessive quantifier forbids backtracking).

`[0-9]*?` has a non-greedy quantifier to be sure to find the first repeated sequence.

Comment: I thought about that too, but this will not match `0.00000101`, though the OP didn't really refer to this case.

Comment: @Kobi: since he wants to ignore zeros after the decimal point, this example must not return a match.

Comment: Thats correct casimir, i just modded your example. I don't want to check for single-character recursion in the number, only recursion of more than one. So I modified the last + to {2,}

Comment: I don't know. Maybe. `0.00090101` and `0.010101` match, but `0.000101` and `0.0101` don't?  The question is a little weird.